# How to modify a windows 8 tile property

Tags: windows-8

I would like to launch firefox and connect to hotmail when I click on windows mail tile of the windows 8 start screen. But I still want the tile to show dynamic value on it (number of unread msg and so on).

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.